# Drag and Drop List Item from one ListView to another and update in database depending on where item is dropped

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, listview, drag-and-drop

Attempting to create a Storyboard in which user stories (list item) can be dragged and dropped from one ListView to another. Depending on which ListView the item is dropped into, the item's status is then updated in database.

Below are the data sources for each list view. Items from database displayed in corresponding ListView based on the status field. Status can be one of four: NULL, Started, Blocked, Completed

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="return_stories" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:Scrumdog_Millionaire.Properties.Settings.DB_CONN %>'
            SelectCommand="SELECT stories.storyID, stories.sprintID, stories.story_name, stories.status, users.first_name FROM stories INNER JOIN users ON stories.userID = users.userID WHERE stories.status IS NULL">
        </asp:SqlDataSource> 

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="return_started_stories" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:Scrumdog_Millionaire.Properties.Settings.DB_CONN %>'
            SelectCommand="SELECT stories.storyID, stories.sprintID, stories.story_name, stories.status, users.first_name FROM stories INNER JOIN users ON stories.userID = users.userID WHERE stories.status='Started'">
        </asp:SqlDataSource> 

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="return_blocked_stories" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:Scrumdog_Millionaire.Properties.Settings.DB_CONN %>'
            SelectCommand="SELECT stories.storyID, stories.sprintID, stories.story_name, stories.status, stories.blocked_description, users.first_name FROM stories INNER JOIN users ON stories.userID = users.userID WHERE stories.status='Blocked'">
        </asp:SqlDataSource> 

         <asp:SqlDataSource ID="return_complete_stories" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:Scrumdog_Millionaire.Properties.Settings.DB_CONN %>'
            SelectCommand="SELECT stories.storyID, stories.sprintID, stories.story_name, stories.status, stories.blocked_description, users.first_name FROM stories INNER JOIN users ON stories.userID = users.userID WHERE stories.status='Completed'">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Example of one of the ListViews:

```
    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-1-3">
        <div class="pricing-table pricing-table-biz pricing-table-selected">
            <div class="pricing-table-header">
                <h2>Started</h2>
            </div>

            <ul class="pricing-table-list" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" dropzone="true" data-autodividers="true">

                <asp:ListView ID="display_started_stories" runat="server" DataSourceID="return_started_stories">
                <EmptyDataTemplate>
                    <span>Currently no stories for this sprint with status set to 'Started'.</span>
                </EmptyDataTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <div class="block" style="width: 150px; background-color: lightgreen; padding: 10px; margin: 10px" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)">
                    <li>
                         <asp:Label Text='<%# String.Format("<b>Task:</b>{0}  <b>Assigned To:</b> {1}", Eval("story_name"), Eval("first_name")) %>' runat="server" ID="story_startedlabel" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragStart(event)"/>
                    </li>
                   </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:ListView>
                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Using javascript I have so far been able to drag items between lists however I am unsure how to trigger an update method in code behind file. Also uncertain whether best option is to use ondrop or ondragenter Event.

```
        <script>
    function dragStart(event) {
        event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", event.target.id);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Started to drag the selected story";
    }

    function allowDrop(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    function drop(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var data = event.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
        event.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "The story was dropped";
        document.getElementById("story_blockedlabel").ondragleave();
    }
    function myFunction(variable) {
        var s = document.getElementById(variable);
        s.value = "Started";
    }
    myFunction("story_blockedlabel");
</script>
```

First time using stackoverflow so I apologize in advance if my description is too vague. Any help would be much appreciated or another suggestions on how to achieve this functionality would be much appreciated.[Image of current HTML when rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKI4R.png)